# Sencha Touch - won't resize when AdView is added

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2, admob

I have this:

```
private void setupAds() {
    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a15138083566f58");
    LinearLayout layout = super.root;
    layout.addView(adView);

    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    request.setTesting(true);
    adView.loadAd(request);

    super.root.requestLayout();
}
```

When the ad loads, it covers up the bottom of my application. If I switch the orientation, everything re-renders correctly. This must mean that the WebView is the right size, but Sencha Touch isn't respecting the size change, right?

How do I fix this?

Comment: Hi Stefan, Have you been able to resolve the issue? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding an AdView programmatically to would normally add it into a ViewGroup that you have specially created and sized for that purpose. I have no idea what Sencha Touch is but if super.root is the ViewGroup for the whole Activity then your display will depend entirely upon what type of Layout what specified for the root View.

Suggest you create a AdViewParent in your layout and add the AdView into that.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to put adView not onto the `super.root` layout but onto the layout of WebView (`appView` of DridGap). Here is the code for horizontal align banner in bottom of the screen

```
private void setupAds() {
    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a15138083566f58");
    //         
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                AdSize.BANNER.getHeightInPixels(this));
    rparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    layout.addView(adView, params);
    // 
    appView.addView(layout, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    request adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adView.loadAd(request);
}
```

Using this method you have to avoid overlapping of content by admob banner. You can do it in  app.scss, someting like

```
#bottomitemid{
   padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```